# Bitwise operations on boolean values

Tags: php, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

From my knowledge, bitwise operators perform a check on all corresponding bits, as in:

```
echo 64 | 32;   //prints 96
echo 'a' & 'b'; //prints `
```

While conditional `&&` and `||` operators perform operations on boolean values:

```
echo (int)(true && false); //prints: 0
echo (int)(true || false); //prints: 1
```

When I (in my head) want to predict the result of a bitwise operation, I first convert the values into their binary representation (which depends on the datatype). After this, I compare it bit-for-bit, and convert the result into the suitable output type (which I suppose is determined by the operands). Although at one point, I tried doing the same with boolean values, which (from my knowledge) only consists of one bit in memory, making `true` corresponding to `1₂`, and making `false` corresponding to `0₂` (in binary). Performing bitwise operations on these values should therefore produce a similar result as with `&&` and `||`, right? To show you what I mean:

```
true & false    =>      1₂ & 0₂      =>      0₂     =>     false
true | false    =>      1₂ | 0₂      =>      1₂     =>     true
~true           =>      ~1₂          =>      0₂     =>     false
```

(Not including `xor`, as there's no corresponding conditional boolean operator.)

To me, it looks like the behaviour should be really equivalent to conditional operators:

```
true && false   =>      false
true || false   =>      true
!true           =>      false
```

So therefore, I set this code up to test it:

```
    echo "true AND false: " . ((true && false) ? "1" : "0") . "<br />\n";
    echo "true OR false: " . ((true || false) ? "1" : "0") . "<br />\n";
    echo "NOT true: " . ((!true) ? "1" : "0") . "<br />\n";

    echo "<br />\n";

    echo "true BITAND false: " . ((true & false) ? "1" : "0") . "<br />\n";
    echo "true BITOR false: " . ((true | false) ? "1" : "0") . "<br />\n";
    echo "BITNOT true: " . ((~true) ? "1" : "0") . "<br />\n";
```

It gave me the following output:

> true AND false: 0
>   true OR false: 1
>   NOT true: 0
>
> true BITAND false: 0
>   true BITOR false: 1
>
> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\handler.php on line 21

So from this, I have two questions:

1. What's the point with `&&` and `||`, if we (as it seems) can use `&` and `|` on boolean values instead?
2. Why can't I do `~true` (or with other words, why aren't boolean values supported)? To me, it sounds logical that `~true` returns `false`.

I did come up with one thing, being that `&&` and `||` will (sometimes) cast the values into `bool` and thereafter return the correct results, if we (by mistake) would happen to pass a value that's not of type `bool`. But to solve that, can't we just do a cast first? Such as:

```
if ((bool)$foo & (bool)$bar) { ...
```

It feels like I'm missing a major piece here that changes everything... But just in case I didn't, I included as much info as I could. Could someone make me understand this a bit better, by answering my two questions? I'm pretty confused at this point, and I've been thinking about this for quite some time.

Comment: Bitwise operators don't return Booleans unless they're operating on Boolean values, comparison operators always return a Boolean result.... that's one very major difference

Comment: Bitwise operator on two integer values will return an integer value... e.g. (using 8 bits to simplify) `00001000` | `00000111` will return `00001111`; `00001111` & `01010101` will return `00000101`

Comment: @Mark Baker That's true, though that's why I was assuming that an explicit cast somewhere would be suitful (as in my last example). I mean, if conditional operators (or comparison operators) have 2 different values, they need them converted first, right? So wouldn't that cast be taken place regardless of operator? Or are there any other weak points with the last code I provided? (With other words, doesn't the `8` and the `7` be casted like this: `(bool)8 | (bool)7`, even if we'd use `8 || 7`?)

Comment: Why have the overhead of an explicit cast for a comparison when PHP will do an implicit cast to Boolean.... and once the value is Boolean, a comparison is likely to be faster than a bitwise operation

Comment: @Mark Baker True, that makes sense. I guess it's hard to understand how the implicit/explicit casts are performed when not knowing how the bitwise operators operates compared to conditional operators. Can we somehow know how the `&&` functions handles the procedure?

Comment: Well PHP is open source, so you can always look at the source.... but the two types of operators are designed for very different purposes... bitwise operators will work on Booleans, but their strength is working on non-Booleans.... and because PHP is loose-typed, comparison operators are intended to work with any datatype.... and the behaviour of both types of operators is well documented

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Answer 1

Parts of a boolean expressions (`||`, `&&`, `!`, ...) are only evaluated if needed (from left to right):

```
  if ($a | func()) { } // func is always called
  if ($a || func()) { } // func is not called if $a is true,
                        // because expression is true whatever func will return
  if ($a && func()) { } // func is not called if $a is false,
                        // because expression is false whatever func will return
  func() || exit(); // exit() will be called if func() returns false
```

Take a look at the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

### Answer 2

`~true` seems not to be meaningful: `true` is `0x00...01` and `~true` will be `0xff...fe` and not `false` `0x000...0`:

```
var_dump(~((int)true)); // prints: int(-2)
echo dechex(~((int)true)); // prints: fffffffffffffffe
```

Use `!`-operator instead:

```
var_dump(!true); // prints: bool(false)
```

### Résumé

Use bitwise operators only if you need to change bits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there's still one thing I don't get: Why is `~true` the same as `0x00...01` and not `0x0`? Aren't boolean values 1 bit in size? Other than that, the answer to the first question seems great, so thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't ask me why I stumbled into this again, but I read through it one more time (out of interest) and realized that I understand what I didn't understand before. In case someone would ever be interested (which I doubt), I'll summarize: Seemingly there are other difficulties with having single-bit variables related to memory architecture (they are simply too small, and RAM isn't designed to handle them). That explains why boolean values occupy more space and why bitNOT won't yield the same result when operating two boolean values. (I'll accept this answer, since I forgot to do that last time.)

Answer (score 0):

`true` and `false` boolean flags, albeit being stored in memory as 32-bit or 64-bit values, should be considered just as two-states boolean values. You'll end up using it only on brach guards so you should not make arithmetic over them. `&&` and `||` evaluates as boolean flags, bitwise operators & and | evaluates as the same of the operands (e.g. `int & int` evaluates as `int`, `int && int` evaluates as boolean).

the story is:
use `&&` and `||` when you have to take decisions over some conditions. Use `&` and `|` to perform boolean arithmetic over values.

that's C++

C doesn't have any built-in boolean values so any non zero value is a `true`, and zero is `false`.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't quite unerstand this: "true and false boolean flags, albeit being stored in memory as 32-bit or 64-bit values, should be considered just as two-states boolean values.".

Comment: it means that you should not do math over them (e.g. casting a boolean to an int and then bitmasking it with some other variable)

Comment: Doesn't bitwise operators operate on the bits themselves? I didn't know that it required casting, and I don't quite understand what you mean by doing math. With other words, does `true & true` conclude any casts?